# Conficker Anti-IDA packer

Tags: virus

I am looking for information about the packer used to pack the infamous Conficker virus. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything about the packer on the Internet. This packer seems to have used an anti-analysis technique that messed IDA's graphing algorithm, I was told that it is quite a funny site.
I would be grateful if someone that happens to have access to the packed executable was able to send me a copy.
An explanation of how it works would be gratefully accepted as well.

Thanks a million for any answer, this is my first post on this forum and I really liked what I've seen so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have a hard time getting someone to directly post a link to a functional binary of malicious code here.

Fortinet's blog has a good explanantion of how to unpack whatever version of conficker you have. 
[Fortinet: unpacking conficker](https://blog.fortinet.com/2009/03/26/the-art-of-unpacking-conficker-worm)

This technique, with some modifications, will work well for most single-stage custom packers:

1. Run the binary under a debugger on an isolated machine
2. Set breakpoints on anti-debugging branches
3. Modify the registers so the code will run as if unobserved
4. Let the binary unpack itself and dump memory
5. Rebuild an executable from the de-obfuscated shellcode

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! 
I am not sure what kind of Conficker my friend used but he said that whenever you tried to go to graph mode in IDA a gigantic mass of code blocks would be generated.
If you understand what i am saying, do you happen to know an executable that can demonstrate this behavior?
Thanks again, Jonathan.